# Sorting List using lambda and custom Comparator class not working

Tags: java, lambda

I am trying to sort List of Objects that by their name using lambda and custom comparator class "VirusSorter" but its doing nothing i dont know why
Main code

```
List<Virus> tmpVir = new ArrayList<>(OuterClass.getSvi_virusi());
        tmpVir.stream()
                .sorted(new VirusSorter())
                .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comparator class:

```
class VirusSorter  implements Comparator<Virus> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Virus o1, Virus o2) {

        if(o1.getNaziv().compareTo(o2.getNaziv().toUpperCase()) == 1)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else if(o1.getNaziv().compareTo(o2.getNaziv().toUpperCase()) == -1)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else
            return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does "doing nothing"  mean returning an unexpected return value, or throwing an exception?  Please [edit] your question to add what the return value is, and what is expected.  If an exception is thrown, please include all the text of the exception stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

The compare inputs are `o2.getNaziv().toUpperCase()` and `o1.getNaziv()` (without a call to make it upper case), so it's never comparing like with like.

Try something like

```
public int compare(Virus o1, Virus o2) {
    return o1.getNaziv().compareToIgnoreCase(o2.getNaziv());
}
```